# Ant warning/failure when file / build.properties is missing?

Tags: ant, build-process

My teams ant task pulls in developer specific info from a `build.properties` file by using the property file tag:

```
<property file="${user.home}/build.properties.txt" />
```

However, when this file is missing ant continues regardless.  Later on in the build process it then tries to access properties that have not been defined and tries to log into the svn server as `${user.name}` and other similar errors.  These errors were quite difficult to debug, as some of the ant tasks I used did not give useful error messages.

My primary question is: **Is there a way to ask ant to fail-fast if it cannot find the properties file?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can combine available and fail:

Sets the property if File is present

```
<available file="${user.home}/build.properties.txt" property="build.properties.present"/>
```

Fails if property is not set

```
<fail unless="build.properties.present"/>
```

Comment: Gah. You beat me too it. Though, personally, I prefer not to end up with extra properties set unless I'm going to be checking against them a lot.

Comment: @developmentalinsanity I'd prefer your solution, too :)

Comment: I think I will accept this answer when SO allows me, however, instead of setting a build.properties.present property, I opted to test for a property that *should* always exist in the file (and to be honest it is the main prop that is required from that file).  I feel this is cleaner, as it allows me to `-Drequired.prop=val` from command line in situations where you would not want to create the prop file (where ever that would be).

Answer (score 8):

You could add an explicit check first. Something like:

```
<fail message="Missing build.properties">
  <condition>
    <not>
      <available file="${user.home}/build.properties.txt" />
    </not>
  </condition>
</fail>
```

would probably do the trick.

Comment: Although this is the more correct answer to the question I originally posed (test for existence of a file), @oers solution of testing for the properties set in the file is a cleaner solution in my opinion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest, instead of testing for existence of specific properties file, test for property definition.  That way this property can be supplied in different ways ( for example as `-Duser.name=myname` ).

You can give suggested file name in the failure message.

E.g

```
<fail message="user.name property is not set.
    It is usually defined in ${user.home}/build.properties.txt">
  <condition>
    <not><isset property="user.name"/></not>
  </condition>
</fail>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used the syntax @oers suggested to implement this idea.  I noted this in the comments to his answer, the `-D` syntax can be very useful for cronjobs etc. so I approve of this method.

Answer (score 2):

Use target "loadproperties" ant task instead of "property  file 
="…">, because the latter task doesn’t complain if a file is missing which is your case. 
The loadproperties task will always fail the build in such a situation where the properties are missing.

Answer (score 0):

or even shorter with [Ant Plugin Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) =

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
    ...
 <fl:fail message="Houston we have a problem" test="!'${user.home}/build.properties.txt'.tofile.exists"/>
    ...
</project>
```